# How do I add exif data to an image in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, exif

How do I add exif data to a JPG or PNG in AS3?

```
    var x:JPEGEncoderOptions = new JPEGEncoderOptions();
    var jpegEncoder:JPEGEncoder = new JPEGEncoder(100);
    var bitmapData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(100,100,true,0x00000000);
    bitmapData.drawWithQuality(this);
    var ba:ByteArray = jpegEncoder.encode(bitmapData);
    var file:FileReference = new FileReference();
    file.save(ba, "ScreenShot.jpeg");
```

**More info**
In my app we are letting the user take a screen shot using the PNGEncoder and JPEGEncoder class. They've asked to be able to save the Author creation date and time in Exif. I'm able to create the bytearray and then save that file but I don't know how to add the exif data to it.

Comment: Check out this library https://code.google.com/p/as3-xmp-file/